# Update logged in user account settings with laravel 5 and Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel (any PHP framework actually) as of today but not new to PHP. I created my first project and managed to login using the prebuilt `Auth` system. I created a new route, controller and model called `AccountSettings` so when I go to `/account` it's prepopulated with the logged in users account info (name and email)

```
Route::get('account', 'AccountSettingsController@index');
Route::post('account', 'AccountSettingsController@updateAccount');
```

When I hit the submit button on the form, I can see the form data I am POSTing (name, email and _token);

My `AccountSettingsController` is:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\AccountSettings;
use Input;
use Request;
use Auth;

class AccountSettingsController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('AccountSettings/index');
    }

    public function updateAccount()
    {
        var_dump(Input::all());
        return view('AccountSettings/index');
    }
}
```

I have tried saving the users info via:

```
public function updateAccount()
{
  $id = Auth::user()->id;
  $user = User::find($id);
  $user->name = Request::input('name');
  $user->email = Request::input('email');
  $user->save();
  return view('AccountSettings/index');
}
```

but results in an error saying `User not found`. Understandable because It isn't in my `use`'s at the top. I tried `use User` but that did not work.

Another thing, this type of stuff should be handled in the model, correct? I have been trying to figure this out for hours now and anything I search isn't really related. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Laravel 5, you'll need `use App\User;` up the top of the file, not `use User;` (and definitely not `use Users;`). The `User` model is in the `App` namespace.

Side note: this is unnecessary:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$user = User::find($id);
```

Just do:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

and get cleaner code and one fewer database query out of it.

Comment: that is awesome, so easy! I was close I guess. What about my mention of doing this in the model? or is that not necessary? Also, I meant `use User`, Users was a typo

Comment: @Ronnie Updating the model from a POST request belongs in the controller. Don't move it into the model.

Comment: I saw a lot of people out their doing the same unnecessary query. So sad. I think the `Auth` class is one of the awesome features in Laravel.

Comment: +1 just because of the `$user = Auth::user();`. It seems like a little thing but in a big scale application this can result in a factor of two and really hurt perfomance

Comment: I have to update logged in user's name and phone number in session after updating profile information by form. How to update Auth session with latest user information? Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Please don't ask off-topic new questions in the comments.