# How can I create a profile for a user through a form in my application? I am using laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

Hey guys I'm new to Laravel.

I have one user in my database with name, username and password, now I want to create a profile for this user through a form in my application, where the user can submit a profile image, description and url. I also would like the user to be able to edit and submit changes after. How can I do that?

My routes in web.php are:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit']);

Route::patch('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
```

My form in edit.blade.php file is as follow:

```
<form action="/users/{{ $user->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('PATCH')

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="description" class="edit_description_label">Description</label>

                  <div class="edit_description_div">
                      <input id="description"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="description"
                      value="{{ old('description') ?? $user->profile->description ?? '' }}"
                      autocomplete="description" autofocus>

                      @error('description')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="url" class="edit_title_label">URL</label>

                  <div class="edit_url_div">
                      <input id="url"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('url') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="url" 
                      value="{{ $user->profile->url ?? '' }}"
                      autocomplete="url" autofocus>

                      @error('url')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="create_post_image_div">
                <label for="image" class="create_image_label">Profile Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                @error('image')
                <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @enderror

                <div class="create_post_btn_div">
                  <button class="create_post_btn">Save Profile</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
```

And finally, my methods in UserController are:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
  return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
            'description' => '',
            'url' => '',
            'image' => '',
            ]);

    $user->profile->update($data);

    return redirect('/users/{$user->id}');
}
```

To also give better context, the profile description, url and image columns are not in my User Model, but rather in my Profile Model. I have defined those relationships, so to allow for better understanding here's the code for the following files:

This is the code in my User.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

This is the Users Table file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

This is the Profile.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And this is the Profiles Table file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update logged in user account settings with laravel 5 and Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999066/update-logged-in-user-account-settings-with-laravel-5-and-auth)

Comment: Can you add ```dd($user->profile)``` to the controller before the ```update()``` and tell us what is returned?

Comment: array:3 [▼
  "description" => "this is my profile description..."
  "url" => "https://www.instagram.com/p/BjoCd24D6if/"
  "image" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#980 ▶}
]

Comment: @EdenGaitor, how come the dump lucks the 'user_id'?

Comment: @EdenGaitor, could you edit your question by adding the error you're receiving?

Comment: I included the error in the question. Please check again. Also, perhaps it's worth stating that the description, url and image fields are not columns in my user model, but rather in my profiles model. I edited question to provide better context

Comment: @EdenGaitor, Could you check if my answer is helpful at all?

Comment: sorry @steven7mwesigwa. the link you sent does not provide me with the insight I need to achieve what I want. I'm not trying to change user settings, I only want to allow for profile information to be edited. That's why I created user model separate from profile model. I'm also new to laravel, and I'm using laravel 8 not version 5. So some of the syntax shown in the answer provided is a bit intimidating for me as it is not at all familiar.Nonetheless, I'm gonna continue to try and figure this out. I hope you can help with an alternative. Let me know if I can provide you with more information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229632/discussion-between-steven7mwesigwa-and-eden-gaitor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates)

> The `save` method may also be used to update models that already exist
> in the database. To update a model, you should retrieve it and set any
> attributes you wish to update. Then, you should call the model's
> `save` method.

```php
    use App\Models\Profile;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function updateProfile($user)
    {
        $data = request()->validate($this->validationBag());

        $profile = Profile::where('user_id', $user)->first();


        if (isset($data['image'])) {
            $this->updateProfileImage($data['image'], $profile);
        }

        $profile->description = $data['description'];
        $profile->url = $data['url'];
        $profile->save();

        return redirect("/users/$user");
    }

    public function createProfile($user)
    {
        $data = request()->validate($this->validationBag());

        $profile = Profile::create([
            'user_id' => $user,
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'url' => $data['url'],
        ]);

        if (isset($data['image'])) {
            $this->updateProfileImage($data['image'], $profile);
        }

        return redirect("/users/$user");
    }

    private function updateProfileImage(UploadedFile $image, Profile $profile) {

        tap($profile->image, function ($previous) use ($image, $profile) {
            $profile->forceFill([
                'image' => $image->storePublicly(
                    'profile-photos', ['disk' => 'public']
                ),
            ])->save();

            if ($previous) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($previous);
            }
        });
    }

    private function validationBag()
    {
        return [
            'description' => '',
            'url' => '',
            'image' => '',
        ];
    }
```

Assumed routes.

```php
Route::put('/users/{user}/profile', [UserController::class, 'updateProfile'])->name('update.user.profile');
Route::post('/users/{user}/profile', [UserController::class, 'createProfile']);
Route::get('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Edit your `<form>` `action` attribute to:

```php
<form action="{{'/users/'. $user->id. '/profile'}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

I hope you have this route `/users/{$user}` defined in your `routes/web.php` file.

Add a `$fillable` member variable to `App\Models\Profile` model.i.e:

```php
protected $fillable = ["user_id", "description", "url", "image"];
```

Not really related to the question, but you may also want to add a foreign key constraint to the `CreateProfilesTable` migration. i.e:

```php
$table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained();
```

Since it's a one-to-one relationship, it also makes sense to add a unique key constraint on `user_id` column in 'profiles table '(`CreateProfilesTable` migration). i.e:

```php
$table->string('user_id')->unique();
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth stating that the description, url and image fields are not columns in my user model. However, the relationship is defined in my User.php file: public function profile() { return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); }

Comment: The inverse relationship is also defined in my profile.php file: public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }

Comment: the profile model is where the description, url, and image columns are

Comment: I don't know if that would make a difference

Comment: @EdenGaitor, I've updated the answer to fit your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate on the passed in `$request` object, try changing your controller's update function's code to:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
            'description' => '',
            'url' => '',
            'image' => '',
            ]);

    $user->profile->update($data);

    return redirect('/users/{$user->id}');
}
```

Take a look at the docs, they are very helpful: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: Perhaps it's worth stating that the description, url and image fields are not columns in my user model. However, the relationship is defined in my User.php file: public function profile() { return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); }

Comment: the inverse relationship is also defined in my profile.php file: public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }

Comment: I don't know if that would make a difference

Comment: the profile model is where the description, url, and image columns are

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->validate($request, [
            'description' => 'nullable',
            'url' => 'required',
            'image' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $user->description= $data['description'];
        $user->url= $data['url'];
        $user->image= $data['image'];

        $user->save();
```

Comment: not working. Perhaps it's worth stating that the description, url and image fields are not columns in my user model. However, the relationship is defined in my User.php file: public function profile()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

Comment: the inverse relationship is also defined in my profile.php file: public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: I don't know if that would make a difference

Comment: that cade will be update and save on your database.that is only validation of data.

Comment: can you send your model code you will define the profile relationship

Comment: the profile model is where the description, url, and image columns are

Comment: so how can you include the user model in your controller.your main model is profile.

Comment: can you send profile mode. and user_id as foreign incude on your profile table

Comment: user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class ,'foreign_key', 'owner_key'); }

Comment: I edited the question for you to see the profile model better with corresponding relationships. It's there if you check

Comment: value="{{ old('description') ?? $user->description ?? 'default' }}"  remove the profile on value in blade file

Comment: value="{{ old('description') ?? $user->url ?? }}"

Comment: you can set your old value image